# Enforcing single relationships between Laravel models

Tags: eloquent, relationship, laravel-8, polymorphic-associations

I am designing an application for school portal and I have three models:

- User
- Teacher
- Student

And maybe a pivot table "school_user".

- Where User could be either Teacher or Student but not both.
- Teachers and Students are added by school management first, then if a user registered he can assign himself to a Teacher or a Student account.

The problem is `user_id` is UNIQUE in both tables [Teachers & Student] so I can't use this field as a valid association.

I figured that I might use a pivot table may be `school_user`,
But I can't find out how to do it.

Here are my tables:

> User :
>
> - id
> - name
>
> Teacher :
>
> - id
> - name
>
> Student :
>
> - id
> - name
>
> School_User:
>
> - user_id
> - model_id
> - model_type

How can I build relations that ensure that the user has only one association to either Teacher or Student?

Comment: You've tagged the question with `polymorphic-associations` so have you tried a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)? What problems did you encounter? Including your code will help others figure things out.

Comment: Why don't you just make a table where you describe all posible positions a user can have (user, student, teacher) and design a user table where you have ID, name, position_id? You can then add another table where you describe relations (ID, user_id, teacher_id) and you make user_id unique.

Comment: **Note** : Editing User table is not available option !

Comment: Emoji should not be used in your title or post unless they are directly relevant to your question or answer. In particular, emoji should **not** be used in titles to call attention to your post. Please see: "[What's the limit to how many emojis a question can have?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390747/3773011)"